# Magento 2 - What is the path when using _scopeConfig->getValue?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to create a block to display store information like the phone, address, etc. I think this is the right way to do it, but I don't know what path to use below:

```
<?php

namespace myVendor\Custom\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class Phone extends AbstractBlock
{
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'what_path/goes_here/phone',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the class `\Magento\Store\Model\Information`. It has constants for all store information config paths.

```
const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_NAME = 'general/store_information/name';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_PHONE = 'general/store_information/phone';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_HOURS = 'general/store_information/hours';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_STREET_LINE1 = 'general/store_information/street_line1';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_STREET_LINE2 = 'general/store_information/street_line2';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_CITY = 'general/store_information/city';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_POSTCODE = 'general/store_information/postcode';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_REGION_CODE = 'general/store_information/region_id';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_COUNTRY_CODE = 'general/store_information/country_id';

const XML_PATH_STORE_INFO_VAT_NUMBER = 'general/store_information/merchant_vat_number';
```